# ERROR in fetchCompletion is not defined - Angular 10 visual studio code

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, angular10

I have an angular 10 project (using visual studio code as editor) with different modules. All modules are building properly but when I try to run(ng serve) the application I'm getting an exception

> ERROR in **fetchCompletion** is not defined

Tried uninstalling and installing the node and cli, even after that projects are building without any errors while doing `ng serve` same exception is getting:

These are the version details :

[image: angular version details]

And These are the error details:

[image: Error details]

Along with the error, it shows the message `** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **`. But when I open the same port [`http://localhost:4200/`] it says `Cannot GET /`. the corresponding request in the network says `bad request`

[image: failed request]

Tried the following actions to fix the issues, but nothing helped:

- Get the latest source code, undo the changes in package.config, and build the project again.(the latest code is working fine for other team members).
- uninstalled the npm and install the same again
- Clear the npm cache
- uninstall and install node js, restarted the machine

Please note: I tried the following command `node --max-old-space-size=8192 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve` as well but still getting the same error. Can someone help me to resolve the issues, Please let me know if more details needed to understand the root cause

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the specific issue because the `loader.js` got corrupted and the corresponding loaded.ts was not getting compiled. The specific file was located at

`node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\resource\src\loader.js`

As one of my friends suggested, I deleted the files and do one `npm install` to resolve the
issue.